# [python]Euler phi function with phi(n)=16

Tags: python

i want to find the number n such that phi(n)=16. I code this.

```
from math import gcd
def phi(n):
    value=0
    for k in range(1,n+1):
        if gcd(n,k)==1:
            value+=1
    return value

i=1
while phi(i)!=16:
    i+=1
print(i)
```

it return 17 but phi(32)=16. how can I do this?

Comment: all from 1 to 16  have gcd 1 with 17. so 17 is correct?

Comment: i want to find all 'n' such that phi(n)=16

Comment: well you will need to run an infinte loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from math import gcd
def phi(n):
    value=0
    for k in range(1,n+1):
        if gcd(n,k)==1:
            value+=1
    return value

i=1
while True:       #infinite loop
    if phi(i)==16:
        print(i)
    i+=1
```

Note that this is an infinite loop. It will keep running even after all phi(i)==16 values are found